# datetime object in a list of lists - how can I get the total for each day?

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have a dictionary and the following shows the first 3 values as a list:

```
day_counts_list = day_counts.values()
day_counts_list[:3]

[[(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 815),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 700),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 614),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2395),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2723),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2543),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2123)],
 [(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 1343),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 1039),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 1145),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2470),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2578),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2439),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2065)],
 [(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 1387),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 1292),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 1449),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2023),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2155),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2284),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2354)]]
```

I would like to have a list of the total for each day. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried something or gave us to do your homework?

Comment: I am new to python and trying to learn by myself @manetsus

Comment: Sure, but this platform is for them who are trying and got stack in anywhere. Then they would present their effort, then people would help you eagerly

Answer (score 2):

Using a regular dictionary:

```
totals = {}

for group in your_list:
    for date, count in group:
        if date not in totals:
            totals[date] = count
        else:
            totals[date] += count

print totals
```

Using `collections.defaultdict(int)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

day_count_totals = defaultdict(int)
for group in your_list:
    for date, count in group:
        day_count_totals[date] += count

print day_count_totals
```

Comment: Using a `collections.defaultdict(int)` would tidy that up a bit.

Comment: Also, you wouldn't want to check `if tup[0] not in totals.keys()`, instead, simply `if tup[0] not in totals`.  And lastly, you can unpack the date and count in one shot with `for date, count in tuples`.

Answer (score 2):

Since each sublist has unique "keys", this can be one-lined (aside from the import):

```
from collections import Counter

total_day_counts = sum(map(Counter, map(dict, day_counts_list)), Counter())
```

In Python 3.3+, you could optimize it significantly (to avoid creating so many intermediate `Counter` objects) by taking advantage of the new support for in-place addition that works with plain `dict` that means only one `Counter` is created and updated, not two per input:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import reduce
from operator import iadd

total_day_counts = reduce(iadd, map(dict, day_counts_list), Counter())
```

In tests on Python 3.5, the first solution (with more temporary intermediates) takes about 2-3x as long as the second solution for the same inputs (and `sum` beats the otherwise equivalent `reduce(operator.add, ...)` by a small but consistent margin presumably due to `sum` hard coding steps in the reduction operation in C).

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Counter'

Comment: Ah, boo. `sum` must be rather more restrictive than I thought. I'll fix, one sec.

Comment: Fixed, `reduce(add, ...)` is logically equivalent to `sum(...)`, but without `sum`'s special casing of numeric addition.

Comment: 'reduce` works.  This is great, though.  I didn't know you could add Counters!

Comment: `reduce()` works but [there is a reason it is retired from builtin namespace](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196).

Comment: you could write it as: `counts = Counter()` `for group in day_counts_list: counts.update(dict(group))` that creates only one `Counter` object.

Comment: Yeah, but that's way less fun. :-)

Comment: @saulspatz: FYI, `sum` works (and is slightly faster than `reduce(add, ...)`, you just have to explicitly pass the initial value as an empty `Counter` or it uses `0`, which causes that `TypeError`. I've updated the answer to use `sum` for simplicity (and minor speed boost), but preserved an example (Python 3.3+ required sadly) using `reduce` with `operator.iadd` that avoids creation of all the intermediate `Counter`s involved in non-in-place addition.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ll = [[(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 815),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 700),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 614),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2395),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2723),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2543),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2123)],
 [(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 1343),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 1039),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 1145),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2470),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2578),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2439),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2065)],
 [(datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 1387),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 1292),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 1449),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 2023),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 2155),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 2284),
  (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 2354)]]

def count_total_for_date(times_list):

    """
    compute total for each date in datetime.date list
    :param times_list:
    :return:
    """

    from operator import itemgetter
    from itertools import groupby

     # flatten datime list
    li = [l for el in times_list for l in el]

    # sort by date
    li = sorted(li, key=itemgetter(0))

    # group by date
    fl = [(k,list(v)) for k,v in groupby(li,key=itemgetter(0))]

    # remove first element, that is the date, repeating itself
    clean_list = [ el[1] for el in fl]

    # this will select data for the date
    dat = lambda x : x[1]

    # create date and total sum for the date tuple
    li_of_sums =  [(x[0][0],sum(map(dat,x))) for x in clean_list]

    return li_of_sums


for d in list(count_total_for_date(ll)):
    print(d)
```

**output**

```
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 23), 3545)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 24), 3031)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 25), 3208)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 26), 6888)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 27), 7456)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 28), 7266)
    (datetime.date(2015, 5, 29), 6542)
```